# JQuery Mobile 1.3.1 "$.mobile.loading" not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cordova, jquery-mobile-loader

I have the following code:

**HTML:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css"/>
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).on({
  ajaxStart: function() { 
    $.mobile.loading('show');
    console.log('getJSON starts...');
  },
  ajaxStop: function() {
    $.mobile.loading('hide');
    console.log('getJSON ends...');
  }    
});
```

I'm using Jquery Mobile 1.3.1 and testing this code in mozilla firefox and google chrome at the moment. I'm going to use it in a phonegap app later on.

I'm loading a JSON and displaying it on screen in a listview. While it loads, I want the program to show a "loading spinner". Console log shows that ajaxStart is firing but there is no visual spinner anywhere on the screen.

What am I doing wrong? Please Help!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

What jQuery Mobile documentation is lacking information regarding successful execution of:

```
$.mobile.loading('show');
```

and

```
$.mobile.loading('hide');
```

They will show **ONLY** during the **`pageshow`** event. In any other case you need to wrap them into the **`setinterval`**, like this:

In case you don't know anything about **`pageshow`** and rest of jQuery Mobile page events take a look at this **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/)**, it is my personal blog. Or find it **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600)**.

First, you will not be able to show/hide **`AJAX`** loader without set interval. There's is only one situation where this is possible without and that is during the **`pageshow`** event. In any other case **`setinterval`** is needed to kick start the loader.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/Zr7Gf/

```
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        $.mobile.loading('show');
        clearInterval(interval);
    },1);    

    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        $.mobile.loading('hide');
        clearInterval(interval);
    },1);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I can't see the provided example working but i made mine work with your help!

Comment: @Gajotres - may the SO lord grant you with the highest of all reputes :P

Comment: This answer is a life saver!

Answer (score 16):

Wrapping it in `setTimeout` works. I just have a simple function to do it:

```
function loading(showOrHide) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.mobile.loading(showOrHide);
    }, 1); 
}
```

Then just call it when you want to show or hide the spinner:

```
loading('show');
```

or

```
loading('hide');
```

Here's a silly jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7UpW5/

Comment: Does. Call it from the "beforeSend: func...". Also, add the "async: false" parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Inside AJAX call? (but will work anywhere)

```
$.ajax({ url: ..., 
    type:'post', dataType:'json',
    data:{ d: ... }, 
    beforeSend: function() { fSpinner('show'); },
    complete: function(){ fSpinner('hide'); },
    success: function( res ){...},
    error: function(e){ alert('Error: ' + e.responseText) }
});
```

And the function itself:

```
function fSpinner( strShowOrHide ) {
    setTimeout( function(){
        $.mobile.loading( strShowOrHide );
    }, 1); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the code for the **other answers did not work for me** and is not complete (e.g. if you like to **pass parameters eventually** or **just use boolean `true/false`** for toggling.
The following provides a nice way to do this:

```
/** workaround: $.mobile.loading not working correctly: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17725350 */
function showLoading( on, params ) {  // on: true|false
    setTimeout( function() {
      if ( on )
        $.mobile.loading( "show", params );
      else {
        //$.mobile.loading( "hide" );  // does not seem to work (e.g. using with GWT and jQM 1.4.3)
        $('.ui-loader').remove();  // removes the loader div from the body
      }       
    }, 1);
}
```

use it like this:

```
showLoading( true );  // show loader
showLoading( false );  // hide loader
```